# “ The survey contains errors: 1. Click here to go to an error.” at survey123

Tags: arcgis-survey123, arcgis-survey123-connect

I published the form I made in connect on the web and when I fill it out to try it, it gives an error like this. What can I do? [image]

Comment: So if you click where it says, it should scroll to one of the answers that contains an error.  What are the requirements for that question?  Does the value entered match the requirements?  What about all the other questions?

Comment: I couldn't understand where the place went when I clicked because I made a secret question. Then I thought it was because I made the date question a secret question. When I removed the date question, the error went away. But if I want to add it again, how do I add it? I want the date information to be retrieved while filling the form confidentially and automatically.

Comment: Do you mean a hidden question?  In any case, you may want to ask a new question here if you need that answered.